# Time to excecute function goes up instead of down instead of up as x increases - Range()

Tags: python, performance, time, range

My bad if this is a bit nooby or I don't understand how this works. I'm trying to get the time of `range(1,x)` using the code below.

**Code**

```
import timeit
def main(x):
    return range(1,x)
def timeThem(x):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    main(x)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    return stop - start
for i in range(5):
    print(timeThem(i))
```

Now I would expect since x is getting larger in `range(1,x)` the time it would take to execute this would be longer. What i'd guess it would look something like this.

**Expected Output**

> .01 .02 .03 .04 .05

But no, my time output gets shorter for some reason. As shown below I get something totally different than what I had imagined.

**Received Output**

```
8.219999999975469e-07
6.740000000060586e-07
1.0670000000004287e-06
4.939999999967193e-07
4.420000000032731e-07
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or do I just not understand how this really works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `range` documentation:

> Return **an object that produces a sequence** of integers from start (inclusive) to stop (exclusive) by step.

`range` do not produce the actual sequence so it can **run in constant time**. Note that iterating over the results is done in linear time.

Furthermore, your values are too small to see any significant difference in the timing even if `range` would run in linear time. Consequently, **you are measuring noise**.

Comment: So basically, I could have a hundred element's in a range, compared to one, and I would still get around the same time? Also why would the times have such a drastic difference. `9.579999999953515e-07 and
1.1359999999988046e-06`

Comment: @BuddyBobIII roughly 10% difference is "drastic"?

Comment: Yes. You can for example test that `45978564 in range(1_000_000_000_000_000)` run in a very short time because of the result produced by range. As for the timing, at the granularity of the microsecond, the timing will not be accurate at all because of your processor (frequency scaling, branch prediction, etc.), the interpreter and the operating system.

Comment: Can anyone give me an example where I would see an expected time change?

Comment: I do not understand your question but if you want to test a case where the computation is done in linear time you can try to build a list (with all the item) from the sequence object using `return list(range(1,x))` and use much bigger `x` values (using for example `for i in range(0,100000,1000)` for calling `timeThem`).

Answer (score 1):

1. your main function only returns a generator

```
    def main(x):
        return range(1,x)
```

Basically, a generator is not executed right away but an iterator with two values and no evaluation of it yet. So it does not matter whether you give `x=1`, `x=100` or `x=1000000`. From a performance view Its basically returns a tuple like

```
def main(x):
    return (1,x)
```

This is due to the nature of a **generator** that it's just get evaluated if you iterate over it. E.g. `list(range(0, <infity>) )` would brake your memory but `for i in range(0,<infity>): print(i)`  would just take forever to compute.

So `range(x, 1000 )` did just create one object - it did not evaluate it

2. please be aware that python has some other coding standards than other languages like java or javascript where `timeThem` is a proper name, but in python, we follow pep8 that says one should use snake-case like `time_them`.
   Personally, I would recommend you to use something like `time_function` to be even more explicit about what your function is supposed to do.